# How to `--assume-unchanged` file in project?

Tags: git, git-assume-unchanged

I have config file: `conf/local.conf` I run next command for it:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged local.conf
```

and it is OK until I switch to another branch or pull.

How to preserve `--assume-unchanged` flag between branches?

**UPD**
Some examples what is coming on:

```
$ git checkout 296-ToS-component 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    conf/local.conf
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
$ git checkout -f 296-ToS-component 
error: Entry 'conf/local.conf' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

I want it works as next:

1. conf/local.conf is saved
2. Branch is switched
3. conf/local.conf is replaced by saved version

Comment: You shouldn't use `gc` in questions because it's your local alias not universally understandable. Please [edit] the question and replce it with `git checkout`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `--assume-unchanged` that should be used for performance problem for big files not changing and that are costly to hash when doing a `git status`.

What you want is `--skip-worktree` that do nearly the same things but to handle files that you changed but don't want to commit.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372

And it will probably (not sure, but hey!, that's what you must do...) fix your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the assume-unchanged bit:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged local.conf
```

Save it:

```
git stash
```

Switch the branch:

```
git checkout 296-ToS-component
```

Retrieve the saved version:

```
git show stash@{0}:local.conf > local.conf
```

or merge the saved version with the current version:

```
git stash apply
```

and there might be conflicts which can be manually solved.

Set the assume-unchanged bit:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged local.conf
```

Comment: And all of this I wanna to escape. Maybe is there an option like `rebase.autostash true`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Maybe make a bash function that takes a branch name and the stashed file path as parameters.